# Why did Firefox 16 change the direction of my linear gradients?

Tags: firefox, css

Sample CSS:

```css
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #e8f0ff, #ffffff);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #e8f0ff, #ffffff);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #e8f0ff, #ffffff);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #e8f0ff, #ffffff);
background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #e8f0ff, #ffffff);
```

This used to result in a linear gradient going from `#e8f0ff` at the bottom, to `#fff` at the top.

Post-Firefox 16 (released a few days ago), the gradient now goes from `#e8f0ff` at the left, to `#fff` at the right.

When I remove the vendor-specific CSS and leave just:

```css
background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #e8f0ff, #ffffff);
```

Nothing happens. But when I delete that line and leave just the vendor-specific styles:

```css
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #e8f0ff, #ffffff);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #e8f0ff, #ffffff);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #e8f0ff, #ffffff);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #e8f0ff, #ffffff);
```

It corrects the problem.

So what's happening here that's new in FF16? Are the `Xdeg` values starting from a new direction, are they being added together only in certain situations? I can't figure out why it would do `180deg` with both or with only general, but only `90deg` if it's only vendor.

The question is, what are the specifics of this new behavior from Firefox, and what's the broadest, most standards-compliant solution for websites that now have their gradients going the wrong way in FF16?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[The standard](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-images/#linear-gradients) dictates that angles are measured clockwise starting from 0° = upward.

> #### using angles
>
> For the purpose of this argument, ‘0deg’ points upward, and positive angles represent clockwise rotation, so ‘90deg’ point *[sic]* toward
>   the right.

[`-moz-linear-gradient`, on the other hand, uses polar coordinates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/linear-gradient) (emphasis mine):

> A last semantic curiosity still exists between the prefixed variants and the unprefixed proposal. Following the initial Apple proposal, the prefixed variants of the syntax all uses the an `<angle>` defined like polar angles, that is with 0deg representing the East. To be coherent with the rest of CSS, the specification defines an angle with 0deg representing the North. **To prevent sites using prefixed version of the property to get suddenly broken, even when adapting to the otherwise forward-compatible final syntax, they keep the original angle definition (0deg = East). They will switch to the correct spec when unprefixing the property.** Also, as they aren't incompatible, Gecko supports, prefixed, both the syntax with the to keyword and without. Here again, the syntax without the keyword will be dropped when unprefixing.

Comment: Then why did it behave differently in FireFox 15? And why does it still go from #e8f0ff at the bottom to #fff at the top in the latest version of Chrome?

Comment: @ch7527: Firefox 15 hadn't unprefixed `linear-gradient`, and neither has Chrome.

Comment: So would a good solution be to rewrite the unprefixed linear-gradient property with the assumption that 0deg = "up"?

Comment: @ch7527: Yes. And it's not an assumption, that's what we have standards for :)

Comment: Good explanation and citations, everything works great and makes sense again. Thanks minitech.

Comment: That'll teach those pesky Web authors not to blindly copy and paste prefixed declarations; speaking of which, if you're using [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree), note that it will handle all these differences gracefully for you, as long as you use the standardized gradient syntax (and you keep the script up to date!) - http://lea.verou.me/2012/07/important-prefix-free-update

Comment: I've fixed with setting only linear-gradient: example: linear-gradient(180deg, #82c039, #bbdd58);

Comment: @jmav: Unless you have prefix-free or don't care, that's not going to work on Firefox 15 or lower, any version of Chrome as of yet, or any version of Safari, or Opera.

Comment: Here is a detailed explanation https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/07/aurora-16-is-out/

Answer (score 0):

A simple hack can be to use the keyword `bottom` instead of degrees.